# Font Awsome icons are not displayed in jsp page

Tags: jsp, fonts

I would like to display Font Awsome icons in my jsp page. It is displaying perfectly in html page, but when I copied the same code to jsp page the icons are not displaying.

I checked css path, it is same as html. I even tried inline css, it works for other styling but not for the icons.

Here is the code sample -

```
<div class="page-sections">
    <div class="page-section">
        <a href="#" title="My App">
            <span class="page-section-box box-teal">
                <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
                <span class="box-bg-overlay"></span>
            </span>
            My App
        </a>
    </div>
```

Also included the css file

Comment: Can you post your project structure?

Comment: Hello Surendar, I am unable to attach image of the project structure. But I have included Fonts folder and also FontAwsome CSS. I am also referenging this CSS in <head> tag of my JSP page.